# Getting Album Art Path null in MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART

Tags: android

I'm trying to get Album art of all albums in my code but I get Null from the below code:-

```
 private void listAlbum() {
        String where = null;

        final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        final String _id = MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID;
        final String album_name = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM;
        final String artist = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST;
        final String albumart = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART;
        final String tracks = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.NUMBER_OF_SONGS;

        final String[] columns = { _id, album_name, artist, albumart, tracks};
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, columns, where, null, album_name+" ASC");

        if(cursor!=null && cursor.moveToFirst()){

            do {

                long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(_id));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(album_name));
                String artist2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(artist));
                String artPath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(albumart));
                int nr =Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(tracks)));

                albumName.add(name);
                albumTrack.add(nr+" Songs ");
                albumArt.add(artPath);
                albumArtist.add(artist2);
                albumId.add(id);
                Log.d("EasysPlay","Art Url "+artPath);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        assert cursor != null;
        cursor.close();
    }
```

I don't know what's the problem in this code. 
I log it and get album art null. 
Does anybody know what's the problem with this code :)

Comment: I have the same problem, after some errors in app I could not load covers although other players can it, but later it works again

Comment: Yup @neosonne, I think it takes some time to load images for new music file.